# how to add custom javascript in wordpress child theme

Tags: javascript, wordpress, import

I have avada theme, and I created child theme, how to add my custom js file in child theme.

I tried using this video tutorial, but without success
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4xbvhXj72kU

Can you help me!

Answer (score 9):

Here is best way to include custom js in child theme:

```
function my_scripts_method() {
wp_enqueue_script(
    'custom-script',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js',
    array( 'jquery' )
 );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `wp_enqueue_script()` function.

documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

This function allows you to load scripts at any given time.

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder in child theme and upload your JS file to that folder.

You can include a js file using

```
wp_enqueue_script()
```

or you can use

```
<script src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/js/filename.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

add the above code in theme header.php or footer.php